# Hooking up a loop-powered 24V NPN/PNP sensor to Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, opto-isolator, npn, pnp

I have a 24V pressure switch that is loop powered.  Here is the [manual/datasheet](https://content2.smcetech.com/pdf/Manuals/PSxx-OMP0001Eim.pdf).  I'm trying to figure out how to read the sensor with an Arduino.

Obviously, the Arduino can't handle 24V, so I got some optocouplers ([manual/datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/2941374-Phoenix-Contact-datasheet-83960795.pdf))

The original schematic looked like this:
[image: Original Schematic]

This, however, didn't seem to work.  When I measured voltage across ports #1 and #2 (from the schematic), it measured between ~13V and ~20V (when the sensor was engaged vs not-engaged).

I'm not really sure how to fix this.  I tried using a voltage divider (instead of an optocoupler), but, in my ignorance, I burned up one of my small resisters.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:
New Schematic (the one above is old)
[image]

Comment: I think that either the output of the optocoupler is not  correctly wired (what's DI+ and DI-?) or you accidentally destroyed its LED. To make a test, use a 1-k resistor in series to a 9-V battery, and try to turn ON the LED. Do you see any variation on the rightside of the diagram?

Comment: So you used the optocoupler without a current-limiting resistor?

Comment: Are you trying to scale the signal from 24V to 5V?  If so, use an op-amp with gain of 1/5.

Comment: @next-hack, This is actually an older schematic, my bad.  In reality, this was for a National Instruments DAQ box, but I changed it to an Arduino.  The post has an update of the new schematic.

Comment: Are you using the NPN or the PNP pressure switch? I think you have to order one or the other.

Comment: @Mike, ya, I guess I didn't know what it needed.  Nothing has broken yet :-/  I'll look into an Op-Amp, but doesn't that just convert the voltage from 24V to 5V?  Since the sensor, itself, needs 24V to run, I'm wondering how you would wire it.

Comment: @jonk, to my knowledge, the sensor can do either/or.

Comment: @jojoguy10, The op-amp can scale the sensor output from 0-24V to 0-5V, which I'm guessing it what you want.  The sensor is still powered from 24V.

Comment: @Mike, I'm not as familiar with op-amp circuits, but is this what you're suggesting? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196409/digital-level-shifter-with-op-amp

Comment: @jojoguy10 I don't think it does so automatically. Do you?

Comment: @jonk, the datasheet is in the main post.  It doesn't specify how to change the mode.  It just shows how to wire it to Source- or Sink-Type input to a PLC.

Comment: @jojoguy10 Okay. Given your schematic here, it doesn't seem to me as though you can brush aside the question I'm asking. Given that you are having difficulties, I think it may be worth asking. But I'm not going to read the manual, either. I just wanted to suggest a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final (working) schematic:
[image: Final Schematic]

In the end, I actually ended up using an NI DAQ box (USB-6255).  This would still work with an Arduino though.

Thanks for all the help!
Joe